# ASP.NET MVC cannot convert IList to IEnumerable? Also tried with IList to IList and still an error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Trying to create a partial view with ASP.NET MVC and Ajax. However I keep getting an error saying cannot convert IList to IEnumerable.

A class for my web service:

```
    public IList<Courses> GetHallamUniCourses()
    {
        List <Courses> HallamCourse = new List <Courses>();

        foreach(var courselist in _hallamUniProxy.GetAllCourses())
        {
            _courses = new Courses();
            _courses.CourseID = courselist.CourseId;
            _courses.CourseName = courselist.CourseName;
            _courses.CourseDescription = courselist.CourseDescription;
            _courses.EntryRequirements = courselist.EntryCriteria;
            HallamCourse.Add(_courses);
        }

        return HallamCourse();
    }
```

Then on the controller where the error is coming up:

```
 IEnumerable<Courses.Services.Service.SheffieldHallam> courseHallam = _HallamService.GetHallamUniCourses();
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Show the full details of the error! You method returns `IList<Courses>` but you declaring `courseHallam` as `IEnumerable<SheffieldHallam>` - `Courses` is not `SheffieldHallam`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun here is a rewrite i think will do the trick for you, as well as its a little simpler.

```
public IList<Courses> GetHallamUniCourses()
{
    return _hallamUniProxy.GetAllCourses().Select(a=> 
           new Courses()
           {
               CourseID = a.CourseId,
               CourseName = a.CourseName,
               CourseDescription = a.CourseDescription,
               EntryRequirements = a.EntryCriteria
           }).ToList();
}
```

But all in all it looks like you are missing some coding concepts. What you say is a "class", is a method (the one I rewrote above). A controller method in ASP.NET MVC usually return some sort of result.

so `IEnumerable<Courses.Services.Service.SheffieldHallam> courseHallam = _HallamService.GetHallamUniCourses();` wont do.

Basic intro to a simple MVC controller

```
//The name of the class must be Name+Controller, and it must extend Controller
class SomeController: Controller{
    //This is a method in the controller, it returns a Result
    //its URI is http[s]://Domain/Some
    public ContentResult Index(){
        return Content("Hello");
    }

    //This is a sub method of controller some, it's URI is http[s]://Domain/Some/Else
    public ContentResult Else(){
        return Content("Hello");
    }
}
```

so when you say that you get an error on a controller, the interesting part is where in the controller. If i said that i get an error in the controller on the `return Content("Hello")` then that might not be too descriptive

Comment: Expect that it would throw an exception unless you make it `public IEnumerable<Courses>` or add `.ToList()` to the query.

Comment: Thank you! This help me immensely and solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Change the controllercode to:

```
IEnumerable<Courses> courseHallam = _HallamService.GetHallamUniCourses();
```

Comment: Thank you, this also solved my problem. Much appreciated.